# Oracle 10.2:Invalid cursor with sporadic nature

Tags: oracle, cursor

A stored procedure in an application that I am dealing with is generating a ORA 01001: invalid cursor error sporadically. When the error occurs, many users will hit this error as a response and after some time, it corrects itself and things will be back to normal.

This ORA01001 error is not mentioned in the official documentation ([Oracle 10g Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/e900.htm#sthref409)). But I could see that error coming from Oracle 10g.
I monitored maximum open cursors regularly and there have been no issues.
The stored procedure point where the error gets generated is a simple SELECT (using implicit cursors).

EDIT:
Following is the code:

```
l_sql_point:=12; 
If l_country_id='RU' 
Then select count(*) into l_rub_count from lcs_currency where currency_cd='RUB'; 
End If; 
Begin 
  select group_id into l_group from lcs_country where country_id=l_country_id; 
Exception when no_data_found 
  Then p_lcs_err_cd:='LCD1001'; 
       p_lcs_err_text:='Invalid Country Code - '||l_country_id; 
        p_err_text:='Invalid Country Code - '||l_country_id; --  return ret_result_set; 
End;
```

I get the following error: `xxsql_point:12----ORA-01001: invalid cursor`

Thanks for your valuable help!

Comment: Please have a look at the following link http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01001_invalid_cursor.htm. Could you post the code?

Comment: Following is the code:

`l_sql_point:=12;
  If l_country_id='RU' Then
  select count(*) into l_rub_count from lcs_currency where currency_cd='RUB';
  End If;

Begin
  select group_id into l_group from lcs_country where country_id=l_country_id;
Exception
when no_data_found Then
     p_lcs_err_cd:='LCD1001';
  p_lcs_err_text:='Invalid Country Code - '||l_country_id;
  p_err_text:='Invalid Country Code - '||l_country_id;
    --  return ret_result_set;
End;`


I get the following error: 
`xxsql_point:12----ORA-01001: invalid cursor`

Comment: you didn't gave the entire procedure/function. The code is truncated. I formatted it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, an ORA-01001 invalid cursor error happens if:

- You try to open an already existing open cursor
- You try to access cursor attributes when it's been closed or not yet open

Check you codebase, see if there are any cursors that aren't closed & that you're trying to reopen again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did check that there are no cursors open nor there are no cases of accessing the closed cursors. Please refer my question. The error occurs at a point where I am using implicit cursors. (SELECT query)

Comment: @Vadiraj that doesn't mean that the error is localized to that SP/select statement. You'll need to analyse the fill call stack. Also, don't put code in comments. Edit the question & add it there.

Comment: sorry, this is the first time I am posting. Thanks to Florin for correcting my post with code. I cannot put all stored procedure code here for the obvious reasons. Is there something I can look up ? What is the 'call stack' ? How can I monitor it?

Comment: @Vadiraj call stack - the entire set of procedures called before this one. At the very minimum you must add the source of the stored procedure which is gicing problems